# How to set datetime precision for column type in EF Core 8

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've run into legacy code that we need to refactor to work under EFCore 8.0.2

```
foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
             .SelectMany(x => x.GetProperties())
             .Where(x => x.ClrType == typeof(DateTime) || x.ClrType == typeof(DateTime?)))
{
    property.SetColumnType(property.GetAnnotations()
        .Select(x => x.Value is not null ? (string)x.Value : string.Empty)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x == DateAttribute.Date) ?? "datetime2(3)");
}
```

As I don't have SetColumnType anymore on IMutableProperty I'm not sure how to rework this. Would it be enough if I set precision to 3 like:

```
foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                 .SelectMany(x => x.GetProperties())
                 .Where(x => x.ClrType == typeof(DateTime) || x.ClrType == typeof(DateTime?)))
    {
        property.SetPrecision(3);
    }
```

for all the DateTime properties or there is other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `ConfigureConventions` for all `DateTime` properties. It will be default for your properties. Later it can be overridden in `OnModelCreating`.

```cs
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    base.ConfigureConventions(configurationBuilder);

    configurationBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().HavePrecision(3);
    configurationBuilder.Properties<DateTime?>().HavePrecision(3);
}
```